# Prime Faces 3.4. Choose: Validation Error: Value is required

Tags: primefaces

I have a page with 15 `h:selectOneMenu`  and about 10 `h:inputText`. Posting from `p:commandButton ajax="false"`  gives me 'Choose: Validation Error: Value is required.' error. 
It doesn't tell exactly which of the input elements failed validation. How can I turn validation off?

Answer (score 0):

You set `ajax="false"`, why you do that, so you use validation for what ?
(Why i can not add comment, only add answer ?)